# FBLoginView not responding to authorization in iOS8 beta 4

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to make Facebook login work on iOS8, but ran into this problem. My delegates are set (it is firing correctly when the app is launched), but when it comes back from authorization nothing is firing (not even the error one). I set it up this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let loginView = FBLoginView(readPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"])
    loginView.delegate = self

    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame,
        (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)),
        5)
    loginView.center = self.view.center

    self.view.addSubview(loginView)
}

func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView: FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser!) {
    println("info fetched: \(user)")
}

func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView: FBLoginView!) {
    println("showing logged in user")
}

func loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser(loginView: FBLoginView!) {
    println("showing logged out user")
}

func loginView(loginView: FBLoginView!, handleError error: NSError!) {
    println("error \(error)")
}
```

I don't know what the problem could be, I think everything is set correctly (on FB dashboard, and in the .plist file). Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

The problem was I didn't override the `func application(application: UIApplication!, openURL url: NSURL!, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject!) -> Bool` in the app delegate. Now it works fine!